# How to filter only first level menu links using views?

Tags: views, 8

I have created the menu with the below structure,

- A

  - Link A1
  - List A2

    - Link A21
    - List A22
- B

  - Link B1

    - Link B11
    - List B12
  - List B2

Now my requirement is to get only first level menu links i.e **A and B only** using views module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by adding Filter criteria as given below in views. Please improve this answer if I am not correct.

```
Parent plugin ID (not_begins menu)
```

[image]